# What's the easiest den defense level to get "Iron curtain"?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-revelations

For "Iron Curtain," I have to do a den defense "perfectly," and without using the cannon.  What does perfectly mean?  With my base having 100% health?

I tried to do this on the tutorial mission for den defense, and the battering ram destroyed me.  Should I replay the tutorial mission again later to try this, or does it get easier later when I've unlocked more assassin options?

Comment: They actually tend to get more difficult, more enemy types, etc. Haven't got it myself, so I don't really have an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What they mean by perfectly is, they never damage your base.  I would go back and revisit the first den defense to make it easy on you (Sequence 2, Memory 6).  I would not wait until later on because it gets increasingly difficult to fend them off as they get much more difficult units to handle, *especially* the dreaded **Cannon Siege Engine**.

My strategy is to fill the rooftops first with **Assassin Leaders** as the game would let you (adding forced units when required) starting from the roofs closest to the entrance.  This will allow you to gain passive morale as fast as possible.  And make sure you set your **Barricade** somewhere toward the middle (between the left and right buildings, closer toward the entrance) to give your guys time to shoot.

As for the units to add, I'd start with **6 Crossbowmen** placed closest to the entrance on either side (it's possible to get away with 3 though, your choice) then start adding **Riflemen** working you way closer toward your base.  Also add more upgraded **Barricades** with riflemen on the street to help slow them down.  You'll want as much **Riflemen** as you can to be able to fend off the **Siege Engine** at the end.

While doing this, make sure you're regularly shooting with your hidden gun and looting the bodies to help with the killing and getting more morale.

Comment: I got attacked just now, and followed this advice.  I'm glad I tried it on an easier one, knowing that it gets much harder was helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use your gun, with x on xbox. It's gonna help a lot.